KafkaConsumer is not able to process 2 million records
I am facing issue while fetching 2 million records from kafka topic through a consumer.
My requirement is to fetch the record and store those records into a map and return that map to other methods so they can process and write the final output to a file.
the run method:
public Map<String, SaleRecord> run() throws NullPointerException {
    kafkaConfigurations();

    Map<String, SaleRecord> recordMap = new HashMap<>();

    LOG.info("Started consuming kafka messages....");
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

    int i = 0;
    // int recordLimit = 1000; // Set the limit to the desired number of records


    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        LOG.debug(records.count() + "^^^^^^^size of records");
       /* if (records.isEmpty()) {
            LOG.info("No more records to consume. Exiting...");
            break;
        }*/


        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            JsonNode jsonData = null;
            try {
                jsonData = mapper.readTree(record.value());
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            // Validate JSON data
            if (!validateJsonData(jsonData)) {
                continue;  // Skip invalid records
            }
            SaleRecord priceRecords = mapper.convertValue(jsonData, SaleRecord.class);

            if (priceRecords != null && isValidSaleRecord(priceRecords)) {
                    recordMap.put(priceRecords.getInvoiceId(), priceRecords);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            LOG.info("Done consuming kafka messages after {} iterations", i);
        return recordMap;
        }

    }

So what can be the terminal condition of while loop, if I have to process 2 million records within less time.
I have tried to processing 100k records and its working with terminal condition as 100000.
but I have to process 2 million per day, so its taking time and going into a infinite loop.
I dont have much expertise on kafka.

Use a profiler to see what is using more time. And the infinite loop maybe you while(true). Try with a condition to break the loop.

The producer property batch.size defines the maximum number of records that are sent by the Apache Kafka client to the broker with one request (default: 16384).
Depending on the size of your records, you might want to consider setting this property to a few hundred thousands, typically to something between 100000 and 200000. Please note that increasing the batch.size might have a negative impact on the memory consumption of your application.

If the 2M records are already available in the topic before running this, you could start multiple consumers, each running as a thread, to consume the records in less time.
You could check the number of messages available on a topic by iterating through all the partitions to get the difference between the current offset and the latest offset, and only start the consumption once you have 2M records  available in the topic.In this way, you can have the offsets as the terminal conditions and close the hit those offsets.
